# How to calculate sum of elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code where I'm able to calculate the average of marks but unable to calculate the sum and percentage.

And I want to print the name of the student under student name but I'm getting only the student number.

I tried understand more about these, but was unable to get through.

Could you please help me out?

```
package cube;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReportCard {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int DB[][], nos = 0;
String arrayOfNames[] = new String[nos];
String S = "";
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

void Input() throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Enter The Number Of Students : ");
    nos = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    DB = new int[nos + 1][6];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of student:");
        arrayOfNames[i] = s.nextLine();


        System.out.print("\nEnter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s English   Score : ");
        DB[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s Science Score : ");
        DB[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s Maths  Score : ");
        DB[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        DB[i][3] = (int) (DB[i][0] + DB[i][1] + DB[i][2] / 3); //calculating the Average Marks of Each Student
        DB[i][4] = (int) (DB[i][0] + DB[i][1] + DB[i][2]);

    }
}


void PrintReport() {
    System.out.println("\nGenerated Report Card :\n\nStudent Name.  English   Science   Maths   Average   Total\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nos; i++) {
        Padd("Student Name.  ", (i + 1));
        Padd("English   ", DB[i][0]);
        Padd("Science   ", DB[i][1]);
        Padd("Maths   ", DB[i][2]);
        Padd("Average", DB[i][3]);
        Padd("Total", DB[i][4]);
        System.out.println(S);
        S = "";
    }
}

void Padd(String S, int n) {
    int N = n, Pad = 0, size = S.length();
    while (n != 0) {
        n /= 10;
        Pad++;
    }
    System.out.print("    " + N);
    for (int i = 0; i < size - Pad - 5; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ReportCard obj = new ReportCard();
    obj.Input();
    obj.PrintReport();
}
}
```

Comment: Multiplying comes before summing use brackets !

Comment: @bakero98 it wont return any value

Comment: Hello, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Often it helps to break a problem into small pieces. I suggest that you write another program that asks for a student's name and scores for each subject. The program should do this for only **one** student. Then calculate the sum, average, and percentage for that one student. When you figure out how to do this for one student, it will be much easier to do for more.

Comment: You should really follow the Java Naming Conventions: method and variable names always start with lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing your arrayOfNames array to a length of zero always. You should be initializing it once you get the value of the variable nos ( similar to your initialization of 2d array DB)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the array of names, i.e, `arrayOfNames` as an array of length `0` because `nos` is initially zero. 
Observe this:

```
int DB[][],nos=0; //nos is initialized to 0
String arrayOfNames[] = new String[nos];  //arrayOfNames is of size = nos,which is in turn equal to 0, hence arrayOfNames is basically an array which can't hold anything.
```

instead do this:  just declare `arrayOfNames` and don't initialize it. ==> `String arrayOfNames[];`

define the string size after you accept the size, i.e, `nos`. So it should be as follows:

```
void Input() throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Enter The Number Of Students : ");
    nos = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    arrayOfNames[] = new String[nos];  //now define the size
    ...
```

This would ensure that the string is accessible outside the `Input()` function as well as is defined with a valid size.

Answer (score 0):

Following corrections can make your code run..

```
package testProgram;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReportCard {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int DB[][], nos = 0;
    //here initaialise reference will null
    String arrayOfNames[] = null;
    String S = "";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    void Input() throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Enter The Number Of Students : ");
        nos = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        DB = new int[nos + 1][6];
        //create string array object here
        arrayOfNames = new String[nos];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of student:");
            arrayOfNames[i] = s.nextLine();

            System.out.print("\nEnter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s English   Score : ");
            DB[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s Science Score : ");
            DB[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s Maths  Score : ");
            DB[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            //take extra variable that holds total, it increases the readability of the code
            int total = DB[i][0] + DB[i][1] + DB[i][2];
            DB[i][3] = (total) / 3; //calculating the Average Marks of Each Student
            DB[i][4] = total;

        }
    }

    void PrintReport() {
        System.out.println("\nGenerated Report Card :\n\nStudent Name.  English   Science   Maths   Average   Total\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < nos; i++) {
            Padd("Student Name.  ", (i + 1));
            Padd("English   ", DB[i][0]);
            Padd("Science   ", DB[i][1]);
            Padd("Maths   ", DB[i][2]);
            Padd("Average", DB[i][3]);
            Padd("Total", DB[i][4]);
            System.out.println(S);
            S = "";
        }
    }

    void Padd(String S, int n) {
        int N = n, Pad = 0, size = S.length();
        while (n != 0) {
            n /= 10;
            Pad++;
        }
        System.out.print("    " + N);
        for (int i = 0; i < size - Pad - 5; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ReportCard obj = new ReportCard();
        obj.Input();
        obj.PrintReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to get result in decimals take array of float or double type. double DB[] = null;

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not dynamic. either you declare its size before hand or you use Arraylist..

```
boolean loopNaming = true;
        int i = 0;
        //you are creating array of zero size, use ArrayList instead
        //  String[] name = new String[i];
        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (loopNaming == true) {
            System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            //check if name is 'done'
            if (name.equals("done")) {
                loopNaming = false;
            } else {
                nameList.add(name);
                System.out.println("Enter score: ");
                score = keyboard.nextDouble();
                //nextLine positions cursor to next line
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }
            i = i + 1;

        }
        System.out.println(nameList);
```